# Convert MIDI file into list of frequency values in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, midi

I'm trying to convert MIDI files on the fly into lists of pitches through Mathematica. As the rhythm and time are irrelevant to the list, is there an easy way of appending new frequencies right after I import the file?

Comment: Possibly related MathGroups thread: "[Exporting "Speak" to an audio file?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/tivReXQKLs0/D3p25r0xCh4J)"

Comment: Also possibly related: "[How do I import midi files into Mathematica?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Rcp7amKHSdI/9PTEuSmiaD4J)"

Comment: Also see [the documentation for `SoundNote`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SoundNote.html).